# Drupal SAML login redirect not working

Tags: php, drupal, simplesamlphp

I'm configuring SSO by SAML for Drupal, I tested the SP login through SimpleSAMLphp's panel and it works. I installed [simplesamlphp_auth](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplesamlphp_auth) for drupal and enabled authentication via SimpleSAMLphp.

When I go to https://mydrupal.com/saml_login, the browser starts to redirect (some long URL with `disco.php`) then stops with a 404. The SP simply logs, and rightly so:

`session not valid because we are not authenticated.`

I'm certain this is a drupal or a module config (not the SP or IdP as those are tested and work), what am I doing wrong ?

Should my SP absolutely use Memcache as a store ?

**Update:**
Recent log entries mention SimpleSAMLphp can't find `disco.php`

`page not found 2016-01-18 16:33    simplesamlphp/module.php/saml/disco.php`

Should the ServerName in my VirtualHost config for the SP match the drupal url or is that irrelevant ?

Comment: do you already configure SimplesSamlPhp as an IdP?

Comment: @bekt I have it running elsewhere as an IdP, the SP to IdP flow works, just the drupal module when redirecting, doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that's the way one is supposed to configure simpleSAMLPHP as an SP alongside Drupal, but instead of using a separate VirtualHost for the SP, I added it to the Drupal one making sure the `Alias` worked. The trick was that my Drupal was running in a SSL VirtualHost while the SP was on a different HTTP only port, that's why the redirect never worked. The "*force https for login*" checkbox in the Drupal module config is completely useless

Answer (score 2):

You could be getting these issues for multiple different reasons. This is why one answer is about VirtualHost entries, and another is about your session handling method (memcache or sql).

You didn't mention which version of Drupal core you are running. This is also important with the simplesamlphp_auth module.

If you are running Drupal 8 and you installed the simplesamlphp_auth module via composer, it will have installed the simplesamlphp library in your vendor directory. And it won't matter that you've pointed to another directory for that library in your VirtualHost entries, or even that you've specified another directory in settings.php config. The simplesamlphp_auth will use the library in your vendor directory anyway. This was the issue that I ran into. I had to copy all my config into the files in the simplesamlphp library in the vendor directory before it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your Sp should either use memcache or mysql else it will not work with simplesamlphp_auth.